# Why does the box with RoundedCornerShape have 4 corner lines in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

when i use clip RoundedCornerShape in box,box has a background. internal view has a background.whe internal view was fillMaxSize(),the box still has 4 Corner Line

first ,the code like this ,has 4 corner line

```
    Box(modifier = Modifier
        .width(400.dp)
        .aspectRatio(1.0f)
        .clip(RoundedCornerShape(4.dp))
        .background(Color.Black)
) {
        Box(modifier = Modifier
            .background(Color.White)
            .fillMaxSize()) {

        }

    }
```

then ,i try use `clipToBounds`,still has 4 corner line

[image: the 4 corner line]

```
Box(modifier = Modifier.width(400.dp).aspectRatio(1.0f).clipToBounds()) {
        Box(modifier = Modifier.clip(RoundedCornerShape(4.dp)).background(Color.Black).fillMaxSize() ){
            Box(modifier = Modifier.background(Color.White).fillMaxSize()){

            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: If you are talking about the edge (corner) of box then it is because you are setting the background color as black and when you are using clip it is just cutting the corner based on the value, and hence the background color is getting visible.

You can check it by changing that black color to White

Comment: yes, i am talking about the edge, but the internal box is fillMaxSize， the background should be total white？